# WPF: Can I define/set an attached property through a style?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight

Is there a way to set an attached property via a Style?

I have e.g. a button on which Interaction stuff is set (from System.Windows.Interactivity)

```
<Button>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    ...
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Now I would like to make a style in which that Interaction.Triggers property is set, thereby replacing redundancies by having to specify that property on every Button instance. Is this possible in WPF?

```
<Style Target={x:Type Button}>
  <!-- ??? -->
  <Setter PropertyName="i.Interaction.Triggers">
  ...
```

Somehow I cant see how, but I have seen other examples in the web where attached properties seem to be accessible from within a style...

***Update***

So basically this is rather an issue with Interaction.Triggers not having a way to "Set" something. How am I supposed to reuse a set of Interaction definitions?

Comment: POssible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067876/set-hidden-attachedproperty-through-style

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue with read-only collection properties (the same thing with InputBindings collection). To solve this issue I've created an attached property:

```
public static StyleTriggerCollection GetTriggers(DependencyObject obj) {
    return (StyleTriggerCollection)obj.GetValue(TriggersProperty);
}

public static void SetTriggers(DependencyObject obj, StyleTriggerCollection value) {
    obj.SetValue(TriggersProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Triggers", typeof(StyleTriggerCollection), typeof(ControlExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnTriggersChanged));

static void OnTriggersChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var triggers = (StyleTriggerCollection) e.NewValue;

    if (triggers != null) {
        var existingTriggers = Interaction.GetTriggers(d);

        foreach (var trigger in triggers) {
            existingTriggers.Add((TriggerBase)trigger.Clone());
        }
    }
}
```

This property uses custom StyleTriggerCollection, because standard trigger collection has not public constructor:

```
public class StyleTriggerCollection : Collection<TriggerBase>
{
}
```

In the Style setter you can use it like this:

```
<Setter Property="my:ControlExtensions.Triggers">
    <Setter.Value>
        <my:StyleTriggerCollection>
            <!-- Put your triggers here -->
        </my:StyleTriggerCollection>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: That looks very promising, I'll have a look as soon as I'm back on the code!

Comment: This seems to work, but I am confused as to using a DataContext in tthe triggers. I can't seem to get RelativeSource AncestorType etc. to work...

Comment: You need to understand how relative source works. It works on elements that are in the visual tree. I this case the triggers are not in the visual tree - triggers collection is just a property of an element in the visual tree. The reason why data context inheritance works in this case is that Triggers inherit Freezable. You can read about it here: http://drwpf.com/blog/category/freezables/

Comment: I went down a slightly different route, because I thought I did all necessary steps to support the functionality from Freezable and it wouldn't work. Anyway, some more effort should reveal this works fine, so that's an answer for me :)

Comment: That worked perfectly for me Pavlo. Elegant solution to an annoying issue. +1

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work and I think I'm suffering through what you're talking about with relative sources...but I'm not sure how to resolve... If I bind the same InvokeCommandAction in a place outside of the style, the RelativeSource works fine... Can you offer any advice? Thanks.